# How do we pass parameters to responsive table filters from python?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, bootstrap-4, scrapy

I want to scrape a responsive table that has two filters, one for a simple text search and the other for number of rows displayed per page.

Is it possible to pass parameters to the filters through my request?

Comment: If the filter submission uses a GET request, just put the parameters in the URL. If it uses a POST request, do a [`FormRequest`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects). If it uses Javascript to reload the table, then you have to see whether you can work the requests behind it and call those directly. Otherwise you need to use [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/) to simulate the form interaction. Can you post the URL where this filter is?

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the response. Trying to grab some public proxies https://www.us-proxy.org/ -- the url doesn't change with the filters

Comment: That table is filtered client side only. So what that means is all the data is already there, but just hidden. Do you specifically want to use the filter, or do you want to grab the whole list? The latter is easy: `response.css('#proxylisttable tbody tr')`  or `response.xpath('//table[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr')` will get you all 200 rows.

Comment: brilliant - thank you so much - I can filter it in python. out of curiosity though is there a way to interact with the filter? I'm just trying to understand how it would work / it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you will have to use Scrapy with Splash in order to send clicks and selects to the form ([Splash docs](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-element-object.html)). Splash renders the page along with executing Javascript. Scrapy by itself does not execute Javascript.

Comment: Makes sense - thank you so much - will mark this question answered. I think arguably I could try filtering using xpath tags as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That table is filtered client side only. So that means all the data is already there, but just hidden. To get all the rows you can simply use one of:

```
response.css('#proxylisttable tbody tr')
response.xpath('//table[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr')
```

If you want to interact with the form you will need to use [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/) in order to execute the Javascript necessary to do the filtering.